# Как правильно собрать jar-архив в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Делаю игру на java) Использую Slick (дополнительная библиотека). 
Из под IDE все нормально запускается. Но попробовал сделать jar , так он не запустился(
Делал так "Project->Export->Jave->Runnuble jar" .
Делал чтобы все библиотеки упаковались в jar (эта штука выбирается перед созданием jar). Вес jar'а изменялся но все так же не запускался( 
Дописывал в манифест главный класс - все без толку. Я руками собрать не смогу - никогда не делал. 
Как же все-таки собрать средствами IDE?

Comment: Такой же вопрос, в ИДЕ все норм пашет, а в ОС не хочет...
Возможно дело в:
Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res\\player.jpg")).getImage();

Comment: Это не ответ, а еще 1 вопрос!

Comment: этот вопрос уже был, и уже отвечали. на ваш "дополнительный" тоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create JAR file in Java & Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/) - вот здесь показано как сделать. Правая кнопка по проекту -> Export -> Java -> jar file.

Если не запускается, то расскажите хоть что за ошибку пишет.

А лучше используйте какую-нибудь систему сборки, например: `Ant`, `Maven`, `Gradle`.

Comment: jar то он создает , и библиотеки в него помещает то не работает) 
Скорее всего причина в том программа использует openGL-ские библиотеки и путь к ним явно не прописан ни в проге (в IDE) ни в манифесте) Путь к ним прописан в параметрах Виртуальной Машины как "-Djava,library.path=./natives". Подключал эту библиотеку по уроку.

Answer (score 0):

при создании jar файла там нужно в одном изу трёх пунктов поставить галочку, чтоб в jar импортнулись библиотеки тогда он будет работать и у вас хорошо и на других компьютерах!