# Как создать jar, чтобы он нормально запускался?

Tags: java

Пробовал создавать и просто через консоль и через Eclipse. В манифесте все указывал точно, в конце оставлял одну пустую строку. Но все равно jar не запускается.
(Что-то вроде HelloWord получается делать jar)

---

Думаю что проблема с классами импортируемыми при написании программы. Может они не включаются в jar при его создании.

В общем объясните пожалуйста как создавать исполняемый файл для Java программ **любой сложности**, а не что-то вроде "*как сделать HelloWorld.jar...*".

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: я открыл [поиск ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+jar) и понеслась https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3754/  и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38296 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540/ и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148053/ и т.д.

Comment: Ребята, зачем плодить дубликаты, полно же подобных вопросов

Comment: Maven спасет отца русской демократии. Или Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

При экспорте через эклипс надо указать указать `Libray handling`: `Extract required librays into generated JAR`.